# Add the same word in each string within a list

Tags: python, string, list

Let's say I have a list of strings like:

```
my_list = ["house","table","coffe","door"]
```

I was wondering if there is a way to add the same word in each string inside the list.

For example, let's say I want to add the word "word" in each string.
The result would be :

```
my_list = ["house word","table word","coffe word","door word"]
```

Do you have an idea on how to do that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple `list comprehension` should help you:

```
my_list = ["house","table","coffe","door"]

my_list = [elem+" word" for elem in my_list]

print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
['house word', 'table word', 'coffe word', 'door word']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a list comprehension:

```
my_list = ["house","table","coffe","door"]
my_list = [x+' word' for x in my_word]
```

Manual way :-;

```
new_list = []
for x in my_list:
  new_list.append(x+' word')
my_list = new_list[:]
```